# Load Runner VU Gen fails to record HTTP

Tags: performance, load-testing, loadrunner

When I attempt to record Web (HTTP/HTML) scripts in HP VUGen the browser "Stops Working" and the action recorded is empty. Recording Web (Click and Script) scripts works fine - but is unsuitable for the application I am testing.

My setup:

- HP Virtual User Generator 9.50.0.0 (Build 3210)
- Windows 7 on a corporate network
- Internet Explorer 8
- Chrome 15

When I click the "Start Record" button in VU Gen and confirm fill in the details the browser launches but immediately I get a process error:

> Internet Explorer has stopped working
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close
>   the program.
>
> [Close the program] [Debug the program]

Dismissing the error doesn't actually kill the browser and so I can navigate my application and submit requests, etc. However when I stop recording no steps have been recorded and I am left with a blank action:

```
Action()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Every now and again the process dialog does not "crash" until I close the browser, but it still fails to record.

I have subsequently tried configuring Chrome as my browser in the hope that this would solve this problem however it suffers from identical symptoms.

A quick peek in my event log shows that for each browser I get the following event log errors:

IE

> Faulting application name: iexplore.exe, version: 8.0.7601.17514, time
>   stamp: 0x4ce79912 Faulting module name: bbhook.dll_unloaded, version:
>   0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x496e148e Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x41fa6c0e Faulting process id: 0x15ac Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01ccadc25da25278 Faulting application path: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe Faulting module path:
>   bbhook.dll Report Id: 9f6bdfa8-19b5-11e1-be8f-b8ac6f2deb5b

Chrome

> Faulting application name: chrome.exe, version: 15.0.874.106, time
>   stamp: 0x4ea7969e Faulting module name: bbhook.dll_unloaded, version:
>   0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x496e148e Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x41fa6c0e Faulting process id: 0x1464 Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01ccadc15ed87df8 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   Faulting module path: bbhook.dll Report Id:
>   9cb19ee8-19b4-11e1-be8f-b8ac6f2deb5b

Would anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple:
VU Gen 11.x officially supports IE8.

VU Gen 9.50 does not officially support IE8 and definitely doesn't support Chrome.
Some users [have reported a work around](http://vasanti.org/blog/?p=113) but they do not seem to work for me either.
Conflicting information on the internet suggests that patching software to VU Gen 9.52 is also a solution I could not test this because I could not find a download for this patch.

VU Gen 11.x officially supports IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Installing v9.52 with all patches and the IE8 patch should make it work, BUT only under Windows XP. Under Win7 there is much discussion and dispute about this.

I know for a fact that I got it working, but I do not know WHY or HOW. [Read more here](http://ptfrontline.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/loadrunner-v9-52-or-windows-7-x64-100-working/).

I also suggest you move on to v11 that works under Win7 and supports all IE versions.

As for the failure it is partly related to the BHO installed under IE. This BHO does not work right with new IE versions. The whole of VuGen works badly under Win7 because it was not designed to work there.

Answer (score 0):

You are using LoadRunner in an unsupported environment from both and OS and Browser perspective.   It is not surprising at all that it is not working.   Drop back to your requirements for your tool.   Reconcile your requirements to your environment and then fix one or the other.   If Windows 7 is mandatory then you need to leverage your maintenance agreement and upgrade to LoadRunner 11.